# "I wouldn't have <past particle verb> if you wouldn't have <past participle verb>" not commonly heard from natives, why? Wrong or uncommon?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, complex-sentences, verb-forms, would-have-been

In my native language we often use complex sentences expressions like this: "I wouldn't have gone there if you wouldn't have told me to go there".

Now when I say that in English it feel a bit verbose and weird, and it's very rare to hear that from native speakers.

Is this a completely wrong form?

The other thing is, despite I've been practicing English since long now, there is in my brain almost no trace of what I would commonly hear in place of that (or only a weak trace, possibly having something to do with the use of the Gerund [ing] somewhere ☻, but I don't know really), the reason being, in my opinion, how the English commonly spoken form requires, in this case, a totally different brain-wiring, compared to the language I speak natively.

This is when languages become hard. And this is where I can't but ask for your help :)

Comment: A native English speaker would say *I wouldn't have gone there if you hadn't told me to (go there).*

Comment: is my form grammatically wrong?

Comment: Except in a few special cases, English doesn't use *would* after conjunctions like *if* and *when*.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! What about "I wouldn't have gone there if you didn't tell me to go there", wrong too? Also could you please point me somewhere where to learn this kind of topics? I can google, but I don't know what to search for, to target this specifically! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The past tense can represent an unreal or potential circumstance in the present (e.g. *I **wouldn't** go there if you **didn't** tell me to*) and the pluperfect can represent such a circumstance in the past (e.g. *I **wouldn't have** gone there if you **hadn't** told me to*.) - your second sentence seems to confuse the two constructions.

Comment: Wait, aren't "I didn't tell you" and "I hadn't told you" equivalent in the time to which they refer to?

Comment: The simple past (*didn't tell*) refers to a past event, whereas the pluperfect (*hadn't told*) refers to a past event occurring before another past event.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know where I should look or what should I search for, to find more about particularities like this: `Except in a few special cases, English doesn't use would after conjunctions like if and when.` ?

Comment: *Will/would*, when used after conjunctions like *when, while,* and *if*, implies the volition or willingness of the subject to perform the action: e.g. *If he would be quiet, I might get to sleep* means roughly *If he decided to be quiet, I might get to sleep.*

Comment: What book would you suggest me on this topic, if I had to ask? ;)

Comment: I wouldn't know; these are all just the intuitions of an educated native speaker.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences

Comment: Worth noting: "However, some varieties of English regularly use would (contracted to 'd) and would have (‍ '​d have) in counterfactual condition clauses, although this is often considered non-standard: `If you'd leave (standard: you left) now, you'd be on time.`
Such use of would is widespread especially in spoken American English in all sectors of society. It is not usually found in more formal writing; however some sources describe it as acceptable US English, no longer labeling it colloquial."

Comment: Also worth noting: "Also, in cases where the event of the if-clause follows that of the main clause, use of would in the if-clause is standard usage (this is similar to the aspirin example given above for will): `If it would make Bill happy, I would give him the money.`